# what are .jar.index files under Jboss modules folder?

Tags: jboss, jboss-modules

What are .jar.index files under Jboss modules folder? What is their purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are indexes built by Jandex to allow for a quicker usage and avoid loading classes when they are not required (for annotation parsing purpose for example)